# Angular 4 Observable not working in IE11

Tags: angular, angular-cli, polyfills

Checking param in URL, based on that param calling some other service. It's working as expected in Chrome/Mozilla/Edge but not in IE11. It's continuously redirecting to the same page.

```
http://localhost/oauth/?code=xxxxxx
```

and here are my component code.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.sub = this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
  if (params['code']) {
    this.loginProcess = 'Hold tight! Authentication in progress.';
    this.authenticationService.getOADAccessToken(params['code']).subscribe(function(res){
       // some code
    });
  else {
    // redirect to login page
  }
```

It's getting param code value, after that even its calling getOADAccessToken service call. But before return from service call its falls to `else` part and again reloading the same page, getting param code and calling service and reloading.
service.ts

```
getOADAccessToken(token): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(environment.API + '/getAccessTokens',
        { code: token })
        .map((response: Response) => {
            const ADResult = response.json();
            return response.json();
        });
}
```

It's working in all browsers except IE10/11. Enabled all polyfills in `polyfill.ts`. Enabled `Intl`.
Here are the version details:
[image]

Comment: I'm using mobile so i'm not sure but your `if` statement lacks a closing brace `}`

Comment: @Adrian haha, have removed some other lines. '}' is there in original code

Answer (score 1):

Are you using es6-shim? i have almost similar issues and i swithc to core.js instead of es6-shim. Below is sample to switch from es6-shim to core.js if you wanna gv it a try.

package.json

```
//replace es6-shim
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
```

html

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/core-js/2.5.1/core.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: already package.json having "core-js": "^2.4.1" not using es6-shim.